# Add css to element after an ajax form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a webform in a drupal site that gets submitted via ajax request.

In the PHP tag, I show a form which uses ajax submission and the snippet looks like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['dev-testing'])) {

  $block = module_invoke('webform', 'block_view', 'client-block-139');
  print render($block['content']);
  ?>
  <div class="unique" style="display: none;">              
    <?php

    print l('Download info pack', render($entry_info), array('attributes' => array('class' => array('btn', 'btn-border hidden-link'), 'target' => '_blank')));?>

  </div>

<?php } ?>
```

I want to be able to add CSS to div of class unique after that form gets submitted.

Tried this and nothing works after I click in the submit button:

```
$("button.webform-submit").on('submit', function(){
    $('.unique').css("display", "block");
});
```

Also tried using ajaxSend and Complete. Nothing works

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function() {
     $('.unique').css("display", "block");
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
    $('.unique').css("display", "block");
});
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information to warrant a definitive answer. What does your HTML look like? How are you determining that the CSS hasn't been applied?

Comment: How is your ajax request being sent?

Comment: I just edited the question

Comment: Your PHP isn't relevant. JavaScript acts on rendered HTML. Please show that.

Comment: There's still not really enough info here. Where are you loading the jquery and where is your ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a PreventDefault() to your button of your form

```
$('button.webform-submit').on('click', function(e)) {
   e.PreventDefault()
}
```

This prevents the submit that happens.
Now you can add your change css code

```
 $('.unique').css("display", "block");
```

Last but not least, submit your form manually

```
$('#idForm').submit();
```

Final code:

```
$('button.webform-submit').on('click', function(e)) {
   e.PreventDefault();
   $('.unique').css("display", "block");
   $('#idForm').submit();
}
```

> https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/
>
> https://api.jquery.com/submit/